# Permutar numeros pares PHP

Tags: php

actualmente esta funcion que me ayuda a generar permutas sin repeticion.

```
<?php
$numero = array(10,11,12);
$p = permutate($numero);
$result = array();
foreach($p as $perm) {
   $result[]=join("",$perm);
}
$result = array_unique($result);
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
 echo $result[$key].'<br>';
}


function permutate($elements, $perm = array(), &$permArray = array()){
    if(empty($elements)){
       array_push($permArray,$perm); return;
    }

    for($i=0;$i<=count($elements)-1;$i++){
       array_push($perm,$elements[$i]);
       $tmp = $elements; array_splice($tmp,$i,1);
       permutate($tmp,$perm,$permArray);
       array_pop($perm);
    }

    return $permArray;
}

?>
```

El unico inconveniente es que me genera todas las combinaciones posibles entre esos 3 numeros, en el caso del ejemplo: 10-11-12, me devuelve

```
101112
101211
111012
111210
121011
121110
```

Pero en realidad lo que necesito que me devuelva es algo como:

```
1011
1012
1112
```

Es decir, necesito que me devuelva todas las combinaciones posibles pero retornando numeros pares.

Les agradezco su ayuda si me pudieran ayudar a corregir mi codigo o si existe un codigo totalmente diferente. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Realmente se trata de combinaciones sin repetición, pues el orden no importa. En una permutación hay que tomar todos los elementos y sí que importa el orden.

De ser así, deberían obtenerse C(3,2) = C(n,m) = m!/( (m-n)! * n! ) = 3!/(1!*2!) = 3 elementos

Por favor, confírmame si este algoritmo resuelve el problema:

```
<?php

function c_m2($m){
    for($j=1;$j<count($m);$j++)
        for($i=0;$i<count($m);$i+=1)
            if($i>=$j) $r[]=[$m[$i-$j],$m[$i]];
    return $r;
}
```

En el primer bucle recorro todos los elementos del array, excluyendo al primero. Pues, en el segundo bucle, formo todas las parejas de cada elemento con su contiguo o vecino separado `$j` posiciones. Como `$j` recorre todo el array, al final los habré emparejado a todos con todos.

La opción para variaciones, se obtiene simplemente añadiendo un cambio de orden en la pareja, pero la generalización para tríos o permutaciones aún no se me ha ocurrido.

Para:

```
$ns = [10,11,12];

foreach(c_m2($ns) as $par)
    echo '<div>'.$par[0].$par[1].'</div>';
```

Se obtiene:

> ```
> 1011
> 1012
> 1112
> ```

Comment: Por favor, agrega una explicación al código que compartes

Comment: @Riaven ya está explicada la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias :)